# xslt calling a java method in a class having private constructor

Tags: java, xslt

I am using Xalan and in a situation where I have to make a  java method call from my xsl file. This class has a private constructor and a static getInstance() method to provide instance of it. The method I need to call is getLocale() that returns a String.

I tried accessing the object by defining namespace in the stylesheet definition as:
               xmlns:obj="xalan://com.example.Location"

and using "obj" to access the instance method as:
               <xsl:variable name="locationObj" select="obj:getInstance()"/>

It gave me "Could not find class com.example.Location" error.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Is the class path set up correctly?

Comment: yes. there is not issue on it as i am also making calls to methods from other classes. these classes have public constructor and can easily obtain its instance using .new() method. This is the first time I am having to get into this situation where the class has static getInstance method for object instantiation.

Comment: Then I'd work around by writing a simple class with a public constructor that grabs the singleton and delegates getLocale() to it.